# Linear Regression Variable Selection

Tags: regression, variable

##Linear Regression Variable Selection

Hi I am running a simple single variable linear regression model where  covid deaths per 100,000 are my dependent variable and my independent variable is % of population with iron deficiency. Does it make sense to regress these two variables together or should I be aligning my data and make iron deficiency per 100,000?

Comment: It's totally up to you. Fit the model first, then modify it.

Comment: Or you can use a count data regression model with an offset

Answer (score 1):

> or should I be aligning my data and make iron deficiency per 100,000?

No, this is a bad idea. In that case you will have the response and the regressor *both* divided by the same variable - population - which will invoke bias due to mathematical coupling.